# Wrapping non-IOExceptions with IOException

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to solve okhttp internal exception (and any other possible runtime exception):

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: 
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next()(RouteSelector.java:75)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection()(ExchangeFinder.java:187)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection()(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find()(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange()(Transmitter.java:169)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept()(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed()(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
...
```

Is it safe to add an interceptor and wrap non-IOExceptions with IOException? 
That way instead of crashing the app, just the network call will be marked as failed.

Interceptor would look like this:

```
public class WrapExceptionsInterceptor implements Interceptor {
@NonNull
@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    try {
        return chain.proceed(chain.request());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

I'm just worried if this could leave OkHttpClient in an invalid state?

retrofit version: 2.9.0 
okhttp version: 3.14.0

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do this, this shows a bug and in this case likely fixed in 4.9.0.  Upgrading to 3.14.9 should also fix it, but in this case it isn't supported anymore, so consider adopting 4.9.0.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5605

If the exception was thrown by your code, throwing an IOException would be the appropriate thing to do, but a runtime exception from within OkHttp leaves it in a potentially inconsistent state (hopefully working still).

Comment: Actually, OkHttp version is 3.14.9. I misread it, sorry. And there is no newer version of Retrofit which uses the latest version of OkHttp. Maybe I could somehow make Retrofit use the latest version of OkHttp, but I'm suspecting they might be incompatible?